# How to make OpenWrt router advertise itself as IPv6 default gateway?

Tags: openwrt, ipv6

I have an OpenWrt Barrier Breaker router which is configured with a /48 ULA prefix. Connected Windows clients have two established routes to this space: /64 On-Link and /48 via link-local address. However, I also want the router to be the default gateway (clients to have a ::/0 route towards it).
I tried several options, radvd, odhcp, Luci, but neither worked. OpenWrt documentation didn't help either.

How should I configure the router in order to establish itself as the default IPv6 gateway?

Thanks!